# Large numbers in C

Tags: c, primes, largenumber

I've written a simple program designed to compute and then sum prime numbers below a certain value (1000000 in this case).  I tested it for low ranges and it seemed fine, so I'm fairly confident with the algorithm.  But when I run the code for large numbers it churns out wrong figures (negative numbers sometimes).

Am I correct in guessing that I am not using the correct datatypes to store the large numbers?
If so could someone please point me in the right direction? I've tried a few things without success. Thanks

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

#define NUM 1000000

int main()
{

long int listNum[NUM];
long int n,x;
long int sum =0;

//Initialize the array
for (n = 1; n <=NUM; n++) {
    listNum[n] = n;
    }

//Iterate Sieve of Eratosthenes
for (x = 2; x <= sqrt(NUM); x++) { //only currently works for square numbers NUM
    for (n = 2; n <=NUM; n++) {
        if (listNum[n] % x == 0 && n!=x) {
        listNum[n] = 0;
        }
    }
}
for (n = 2; n <= NUM; n++){  
sum += listNum[n];
}
printf("Sum is %d \n", sum);
}
```

Comment: The highest value for an unsigned long is: ULONG_MAX(≥4294967295U)
you can find that in limits.h are you expecting negative input ever?

Comment: I'll just note that your prime number algorithm is not the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: it is it's just highly inefficient

Comment: What platform are you using? signed `long int` can be in length 32-bits, giving you an upper-bound of 2 billion.

Comment: I can give you one hint right away. You don't need a `long int` for what essentially requires a *bit*. An era-sieve doesn't use the array for holding prime numbers; the primes are the *indexes* to the array where the *flag* in that slot indicates the number is prime. A simple array of `unsigned char` would accomplish what you're trying and consume considerably less memory. In case this isn't obvious, look at your algorithm and consider this: when is a at location `listNum[n]` that you've decided is prime *not* the value `n` itself? *Never*. I advise you retool your algorithm.

Comment: @Ben, the sieve of Eratosthenes is fairly efficient. This is ... something else. It's not clear to me what it's even supposed to be doing.

Comment: Thanks. Negative numbers should never appear as input or output in this program.  Natural numbers only

Comment: I'll agree the sieve is. User2137944's implementation isn't. For every number he is crossing off multiples. `listNum[n] % x == 0` essentially does the elimination of the multiples step. Only he is also crossing off multiples of composites alike.

Comment: Oh, and you're invoking UB when you dereference `listNum[n]` when `n` is reaches `NUM`, which it will according to several of your loop exit condition limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple mistake in your code: "%d" in the final printf should be "%ld".

Which compiler are you using? GCC gives me this warning:

> sieve.c:30:5: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but
>   argument 2 has type 'long int' [-Wformat=]

Then it also depends on the size of long ints on your platform. The long ints on my system happen to be 64 bits, but on other systems they can be just 32 bits, and you could then get an overflow in your program.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't even noticed that mistake.  It works now and gives the right answer.  (I know it's not efficient or a true Sieve of Era.  I'm a novice at programming and was just trying to get this to work before I improve it)

Comment: @user2137944 `long int` is just the same as `long`, no need to write `int` after `short` or `long`. And `long` is most probably 64 bits in Linux/Unix but only 32 bits in Windows. To make sure that the type has at least 64 bits, use `long long` or `uint64_t`, `uint_least64_t`

Answer (score 1):

Standard C offers only fixed-width integer types. If you use `unsigned` ones, they will wrap around at some point. If you use signed ones, they will do whatever they want at some point (yes, really). You may want to consider the [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) library. I don't know much about it, but it's what [GHC](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/) uses for its integers.

#### Edit

As others have mentioned, you should probably be okay with `long` for now; if you end up dealing with bigger things, you can switch to a fancier numeric implementation like GMP.

Comment: Thanks, GMP had come up as a possible solution when I was Googling earlier. Unfortunately I'm stuck on a university machine so I can't download any additional packages.  I tried unsigned long long int and still no luck

Comment: @user2137944, now that I see better what's going on, it's clear to me as well as others that the problem is that you're not implementing the sieve of Eratosthenes, but rather some horrible other algorithm. That's your real problem.